# Vertical placement of figure with subfloat

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, subfloats

In this MWE, on pages 3-4, the graphics are placed further down than on pages 1-2.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfig,mwe}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}%
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}%
\end{figure}
foo\clearpage

\begin{figure}[t]
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}%
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}%
\end{figure}
foo\clearpage

\begin{figure}[t]
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}%
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}%
\end{figure}
foo\clearpage

\begin{figure}[t]
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}%
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}%
\end{figure}
foo\clearpage

\end{document}
```

In particular, the only difference between pages 2 and 3 is the order of images with and without `subfloat`, which I had expected not to make a difference for spacing and vertical placement.

Why is that, and how can I fix this?

Comment: In the manual, I have found that "The figure is vertically centered with some vertical space added above. If this is a float at the top of the page, than the space is suppressed." I feel that the test "if this is a float at the top of the page" fails for subfloats after the first one. Therefore, `\captionsetup{farskip=0pt}` seems to solve the issue, at the expense of changing the `farskip` value for all subfloats in the document, which I dislike.